# Making moveTo and moveBy work on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to get the native function `moveTo` and `moveBy` to work on Chrome. The [naive thing](http://jsfiddle.net/W6QUY/) simply doesn't work.

How can I get `moveTo` and `moveBy` to work on Chrome?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

who said they don't work in chrome??

test on your chrome

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_moveto
   http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_moveby

Comment: Please see the link in my question.

Comment: you must have a Canvas and an object of that canvas on your javascript after that you can do the moveTo

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of some navigators doesn't understand the moveTo(x, y) correctly. The function put your new window correctly on Y axis but not in the X axis. This can be caused because you have more than one monitor. You can bypass this problem using moveBy(x, y) instead.